# Binary polynomial reduction of degree greater than 2n −2

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, binary

I'm working on implementation of some algorithm where the input is an arbitrarily long message m that I need to reduces to its
residue modulo $p^n$ . I'm working on binary fields (characteristic-two finite fields) so p=2 and all the reduction algorithm that I have seen required the input to be of degree at most 2n −2, which makes sense, since you only need to do a reduction after squaring or multiplication and this is the maximum value that you could get. However, is it possible to do a reduction when the input of degree greater than 2n −2?

I read about linear folding in CRC and GCM but couldn't find any good resources that explain it.

Thank you for any input or thoughts!

Comment: What is $p$? What does it have to do with $n$?

Comment: p=2 since I'm working on binary fields and n is the degree of my fiels. I updated my question. sorry about that

Comment: You write about reducing modulo $2^n$, but you also write about polynomial reduction. So I think what you really have is a polynomial $q$ of degree $n$, and you want to reduce other polynomials modulo $q$. And that you can do for any polynomial, regardless of degree. You just divide your polynomial by $q$, and report the remainder of the division, which will have degree at most $n-1$, as your reduction.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. However, division is not efficient for hardware/software implementation. I'm looking for some optimized algorithm such as Barrett reduction that doesn't have any constraint on the degree of the polynomial that need to be reduced.